# Page not found Error. Am new to web development with the framework

Tags: python, django

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/1/
Using the URLconf defined in VibezT.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
  admin/
  music/ ^$ [name='index']
  music/ (?p<album_id>[0-9]+) [name='detail']
The current path, music/1/, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and django will display a standard 404 page.
```

urls.py

```
from django .urls import path
from . import views
#check the URL the user is requesting
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'', views.index, name='index'),
    # /music/71/
    path(r'(?p<album_id>[0-9]+)/', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.
from  django.http import HttpResponse
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h2>This is My First App HomePage</h2>")
#function for details page
def detail(request, album_id):
    return HttpResponse("<h3>Details for Album: "+ str(album_id) +"</h3>")
```

Comment: Which python version is compatible with ~Django~ 2.0.2

Comment: See the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.0/#django-2-0-release-notes) for supported Python versions. Django 2.0 is no longer supported. If you’re learning Django then you should use the latest release, currently 2.2.7.

Answer (score 0):

```
path(r'(?p<album_id>[0-9]+)/', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

Your code is a mixture of the regex `url()` and new `path()` styles.

Using `path()`, it should be

```
path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

Or using `url()` it should be:

```
path(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

Note the capital P in `?P`.

If you're following a tutorial, it's really important to make sure you have typed the exact same code, to avoid problems like this. If the tutorial uses `url()`, then it was probably written before Django 2.0 came out in 2017, so you should think about looking for a more recent tutorial that uses `path()`.